# Apex Class - copy one lookup field and put to another lookup field on the same PricebookEntry object

Tags: apex, lookup-field

:)   On PricebookEntry object, I have a 2 lookup fields:

- Pricebook2Id (standard field filled by Integration)
- Price_Book_2__c (custom field needed for Related list)

I want to fill the Price_Book_2__c using the value in Pricebook2Id.  I am trying to write the class, it will be my first apex class, I invoke it using Flow and later Process Builder, but the field is still empty

Here is my code, maybe you can see what I am doing wrong:

```
public class PriceBookField
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void PriceBookField(List<Id> PBIds){
        List<PricebookEntry> XYZ = [Select Id, Pricebook2Id, Price_Book_2__c from PricebookEntry where ID in: PBIds];
        for(PricebookEntry PB : XYZ){
            PB.Price_Book_2__c = PB.Pricebook2Id;
        }
        update XYZ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: are you calling it from a process builder or flow?    on a side note   you do not need to call  apex  ,  it is doable  declaritevely  in process builder or flow.   example  , just  use a record triggered flow and  assign    Price_Book_2__c   with value of   Pricebook2Id .   you  can also   convert    Price_Book_2__c     to a formula   field   if you are okay  with it  then even you dont need flow.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, it is not possible to choose the PricebookEntry object in Flow, or Process Builder, it is also not possible to write a trigger. The only way is to write Apex class for this object. I need to fill the custom lookup field, because I need to add the custom List view open for customization. The classic PricebookEntry list is not customizable.

Comment: then  you need to execute   your logic from trigger.  what   you have written  now  is an invocable method.   you can write an apex trigger for that.    you can use a before trigger  and copy values  without using soql  and any dml.  go through developer guide :https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm       but it will be very easy  if you can just   crete that field as formula  field .   have you tried  with a formula  field  ?

Comment: sorry  in last comment  i missed  we cannot write a trigger also.  well  it is not like  that  apex class   will execute by itself   you need some event like trigger  which will call  it.   i would  say  you can request   the team  responsilble  for inserting record   to provide value  for this field  also.  if it is not possible    you  can write a batch class nd schedule  it   daily  to synchronize  values   in these 2 fields  . keep it as the last option

Comment: I tried with formula field, but then I will not have List based on that. My idea was to write a class and invoke it from Flow... But the class doesn't  work, I don't have error message, but also the field is still empty

Comment: ok.  i am not sure  about  the list  you are making.if  it is working  if you have  value in the field  then good.   to populate value  you have 2 options :  ask  concerned team directly  who is inserting the data to provide same value  as pricebookid  .   if this option is not possible ,   then you have to write  a batch class   which will run the logic  on your records  and a schedule class  to schedule  it at specific  interval  of time.   https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch

Comment: Will these 2 fields always have the same value or is the setting of the one from the other purely on creation of the containing record?

Comment: Hi Phil! These 2 fields should have the same value, so I want to copy value from Pricebook2Id and put it to Price_Book_2__c - everything is on the same PricebookEntry object

Comment: I see no point in having two identical fields on the same record. Why not simply use the original field?

Comment: Phil, because the orginal list is not customizable, and we have only 4 columns on PricebookEntry List: Product Name, Product Code, List Price, Active

Answer (score 0):

Based on your observed results, the comments, and that your method parameter is `List<Id> PBIds`, my guess is that you are passing in a list of *Pricebook2* Ids, and not *PricebookEntry* Ids.

If that's true, then this makes a lot of sense. Your query contains `FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Id IN :PBIds`. Since Pricebook2 Ids will never match any PricebookEntry id (the first 3 characters of an Id are a prefix based on the SObject), your query is returning no rows. Since it's returning no rows, your loop isn't being executed.

Thankfully, the fix here is simple. You just need to filter based on Pricebook2Id instead of Id (the PricebookEntry Id).

Instead of
`List<PricebookEntry> XYZ = [Select Id, Pricebook2Id, Price_Book_2__c from PricebookEntry where ID in: PBIds];`

You need
`List<PricebookEntry> XYZ = [SELECT Id, Pricebook2Id, Price_Book_2__c FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id IN :PBIds];`

Comment: and if you continue to write Apex, you should consider adopting a naming convention for classes, methods, variables, etc... Like Class names  are InTitleCase, method names are inCamelCase, variables should be descriptive and camelCase (so `pbesList` instead of `XYZ`), etc... That's not a syntax requirement for Apex (most things in Apex are case-insensitive), but it helps to keep things organized in your mind and easier to read (takes less mental effort to read).

Comment: Having a static method the same name as the class may or may not be problematic. If things are still not working, then you should definitely change the method name as your next attempt to fix.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are passing the correct list of PricebookEntry, just to ensure put a check like below.
You can debug your flow to check if you are passing the list of PricebookEntry ids in the Apex Action input parameters. Also, pls check the API name of the custom field created.

```
public class PriceBookField
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void PriceBookField(List<Id> PBIds){
        List<PricebookEntry> XYZ = [Select Id, Pricebook2Id, Price_Book_2__c from PricebookEntry where ID in: PBIds];
        if(!XYZ.isEmpty()){
            for(PricebookEntry PB : XYZ){
                PB.Price_Book_2__c = PB.Pricebook2Id;
            }
        }
        update XYZ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because the `if(!XYZ.isEmpty()){` that you've added does nothing here. If an empty list is given to a for loop, the for loop will simply not execute the lines inside of the loop's block (there's no need to check for an empty list). If it were a null list, that'd be a different story, but a query will never return null (if there are no rows to return, you simply get an empty list).